# Perl strptime format differs from strftime

Tags: perl, strftime, strptime

I'm trying to work with date strings formatted as:

> YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss

strftime format for generating this string is `%FT%T`:

```
perl -MPOSIX=strftime -E 'say strftime q{%FT%T}, localtime;'
```

But when I try to parse this date string with [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time%3a%3aPiece):

```
perl -MPOSIX=strftime -MTime::Piece -E '
  say strftime q{%FT%T}, localtime;
  Time::Piece->strptime( strftime(q{%FT%T}, localtime), q{%FT%T});
'
```

I got this error:

```
2013-11-15T17:32:58
Error parsing time at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2/Time/Piece.pm line 469.
```

Or if I try this:

```
perl -MPOSIX=strftime -MTime::Piece -E 'Time::Piece->strptime(strftime(q{%F}, localtime), q{%F});'
```

I got this:

```
garbage at end of string in strptime: 2013-11-15 at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2/Time/Piece.pm line 469.
```

In man said `%F` is ISO8601 date format in strptime and strftime both. Is strptime backward compatible with strftime?

Comment: All of the above work for me on Perl 5.10.1 on Scientific Linux 6.4.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, you are lucky one:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The module uses its own implementation of `strptime` which doesn't understand `%F`. It doesn't implement its own `strftime`. It's a disaster waiting to happen - you should definitely use a `strftime` and `strptime` that come from the same source. `Time::Piece::strptime` looks like a desparation move from an era without a widely available, standardized `strptime`.

Now that `strptime` is in POSIX, I would expect `POSIX.pm` to export it so you can use your system's `strptime`. But apparently that module is also failing to keep up. There is a separate [`POSIX::strptime` module](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=POSIX%3A%3Astrptime&mode=all) which gives you your C library's `strptime` without interference. I suggest using that.

Comment: Please note: Cygwin uses NewLib for its C library which does not have strptime.

Answer (score 5):

No, Time::Piece strftime/strptime formats are not always compatible. Use the longer version of the format:

```
my $str = '2003-03-24T13:32:44';
my $f = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S';
my $t = Time::Piece->strptime($str, $f);

print "$t\n";
```